# Android volley image url cache is not cleared

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on an android app that has the functionality to upload profile images. The issue i am facing is whenever user tries to upload a new profile image, it gets successfully uploaded to lserver but trying to load the new image via volley library doesn't reflect the new image, ImageView still shows the old image. I have pasted the volley singleton class implementation as well for more clarity.

I tried to clear the cache using both the methods mentiond below but it doesn't work. Also tried to invalidate the ImageView by invalidate() method but that doesnt work either so seems more like a android caching problem here.

If anyone came across similar scenario please help.

1) mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(urlProfileImage, true);
2) mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(urlProfileImage);

Volley Singleton class implementation:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private VolleySingleton() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.getAppContext());
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            public LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024) / 8);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: `// If you don't want to use cache
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            }
        });`

Comment: Even if i disable the caching like you suggested, still i can't see the updated image.

Answer (score 0):

first，like you VolleySingleton it will cache iamge in LruCache and diskCache.you call two clear method if clear both? you must to check it.

Comment: I am not using both clear methods, tried it one by one, but none of them works.

Comment: you try this method getRequestQueue().getCache().clear() ，it will clear all cache

Answer (score 0):

your call to  mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue().getCache() returns NOT the ImageCache but the Http cache (the one from the network)

you need to access the one declared in your imageLoder

```
public LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024) / 8);
```

then you can call:

```
cache.evictAll()
```

to erase all cache or

```
cache.remove(urlProfileImage)
```

to remove 1 item only

Answer (score 0):

**Update Volley ImageLoader Cache for particular URL**

1.Download Image with android way after uploading fresh image

2.Place UpdateImageInCache method in ImageLoader.java file

3.Update getCacheKey method in ImageLoader.java file

```
new ProfileActivity.DownloadImageFromURL((CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_module_photo)).execute(profileImageURL);

private class DownloadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView imageView;

    public DownloadImageFromURL(CircleImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait, it may take a few minute...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String imageURL = urls[0];
        Bitmap bimage = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            bimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            if (imageLoader == null)
              imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            // imageLoader.UpdateImageInCache("#W0#H0#S7"+profileImageURL,bimage);
              imageLoader.UpdateImageInCache(profileImageURL,bimage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Message", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bimage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}

public void  UpdateImageInCache(String cacheKey, Bitmap response)
 {

        mCache.putBitmap(cacheKey, response);
        // remove the request from the list of in-flight requests.
        BatchedImageRequest request = mInFlightRequests.remove(cacheKey);

        if (request != null) {
            // Update the response bitmap.
            request.mResponseBitmap = response;

            // Send the batched response
            batchResponse(cacheKey, request);
        }
} 


 public static String getCacheKey(String url, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, ScaleType scaleType) {

    return  url;
    //return new StringBuilder(url.length() + 12).append("#W").append(maxWidth)
         //   .append("#H").append(maxHeight).append("#S").append(scaleType.ordinal()).append(url)
          //  .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `LruBitmapCache` you should do diable `put(url, bitmap)` :

```
 @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
       // put(url, bitmap);
    }
```

by this way every time you call the volley method image don't save to catch